# Linux large amount of files not being deleted

Tags: linux

I have a folder of cache files in a linux VM that weren't being deleted for some reason.

I'm trying to delete them ( or the folder it self ) but nothing seems to work.

`rm` just gives me back Argument list is too long

I'm trying now
`find ./cache -type f -delete`  , hitting `ls-l` every once in  a while but keep getting the same # of files.

Also tried
`find ./cache -type f -exec rm-v {} \;` but same thing again.

I would be ok if i just delete the folder as long as i recreate it after.

Thank you

EDIT: Ok found out ls-l does not return the `#` of files, if however i do
`ls | wc -l` system seems to not respond at all.

Comment: The "Argument list is too long" should not appear if you use `find`. A `find ./cache -type f -delete` should be fine, why doesn't it work? What error do you get?

Comment: I'm only getting Argument list is too long for the `rm` cmd only. For the find i left it running for 20 close minutes but got nothing.

Comment: Define "get nothing". Don't they delete files? Also, to count the number of files just say `find -type f -printf '.' | wc -c`. It is probably faster.

Comment: Couple of minutes later command is still running...i'll follow @cadrian advice and not stress it any much more. I'll just probably leave the find and delete command overnight and how that goes.

Comment: You might try to redirect the `ls` output to a file, either directly or through a `tee` (running it in a background or from another console), then watch the file growing. That will show you if the listing work actually goes on, or `ls` gets stuck somewhere, somehow.

Comment: Genius, after that its not outputing anything to the file. Looks like its getting stuck somewhere

Comment: If you are really okay with clobbering the folder, try `rm -fr <folder>`

Answer (score 2):

Use rm -R filename to remove large data files

Answer (score 1):

Linux command line length is limited so the `rm` cannot work.

The `find` command will work, though your directory is really big. Launch your `find` command and go to lunch.

EDIT – btw make sure to `ls` the same directory you want to remove files of, i.e. `./cache`. It is not clear in your question.

Comment: Edited the question, actually on `ls` or `ls | wc-l` i get nothing in return, just keeps running

Comment: use `ls ./cache | wc -l` but then I really suggest that instead of stressing too much the file system with find and ls trying to work on the same directory, just let Linux do its work – only `find`, no  `ls`, and do something else meanwhile. It may really take a long time to remove 700k inodes.

Comment: I'll try and leave it all night maybe, but problem is it's using 99% of the IO making it hard for the app to run on the machine

Comment: add some ionice - but it will take longer to cleanup the directory.